# Backup e Restore utilizando PostgreSQL em C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, backup

Para realizar o backup ou restore de uma base de dados através de uma aplicação C# utilizando o SGBD PostgreSQL, é necessário o envio de um comando para o pg_dump. É possível realizar a execução do mesmo através de um select enviando um ExecuteNonQuery (da mesma forma que é executada no SQLSERVER?) ao invés de enviar os dados para o pg_dump?

Comment: os pg_dump é um executável, que deve ser executado diretamente no servidor ou de um terminal informando o endereço do servidor, então pra isso, é bem provável que será necessário enviar alguns executáveis e dll do postgresql junto da aplicação (para executar por um terminal)

Answer (score 1):

Existe um pergunta parecida com a sua, você já tentou utilizar este método abaixo? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026949/how-to-backup-restore-postgresql-using-code)

```
public void PostgreSqlDump(
        string pgDumpPath,
        string outFile,
        string host,
        string port,
        string database,
        string user,
        string password)
    {
        String dumpCommand = "\"" + pgDumpPath + "\"" + " -Fc" + " -h " + host + " -p " + port + " -d " + database + " -U " + user + "";
        String passFileContent = "" + host + ":" + port + ":" + database + ":" + user + ":" + password + "";

        String batFilePath = Path.Combine(
            Path.GetTempPath(),
            Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".bat");

        String passFilePath = Path.Combine(
            Path.GetTempPath(),
            Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".conf");

        try
        {
            String batchContent = "";
            batchContent += "@" + "set PGPASSFILE=" + passFilePath + "\n";
            batchContent += "@" + dumpCommand + "  > " + "\"" + outFile + "\"" + "\n";

            File.WriteAllText(
                batFilePath,
                batchContent,
                Encoding.ASCII);

            File.WriteAllText(
                passFilePath,
                passFileContent,
                Encoding.ASCII);

            if (File.Exists(outFile))
                File.Delete(outFile);

            ProcessStartInfo oInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(batFilePath);
            oInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            oInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            using (Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(oInfo))
            {
                proc.WaitForExit();
                proc.Close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (File.Exists(batFilePath))
                File.Delete(batFilePath);

            if (File.Exists(passFilePath))
                File.Delete(passFilePath);
        }
    }
```